# Whenever I use 'import openai' in PyScript, it gives an error

Tags: python, module, openai-api, pyscript

I am using PyScript to make a simple HTML file to run ChatGPT.
This is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<py-script>

import openai

</py-script>
```

But whenever I run it, it gives this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'`

I tried to use 'pip install', but it gave a different error:

`File "<unknown>", line 1 pip install openai^^^^^^^SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

When I tried to do it on [PythonAnywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PythonAnywhere), I was able to install it on the Bash shell.

Is there a way to do it from Python itself?

Comment: btw, I am using this in school, so it might be blocked.

Comment: also I am a beginner to coding, so please explain in simple terms.

Comment: This is not an easy place to start with. Pyscript itself isn't easy. Start with Python if you are starting out. And ideally start with tasks that don't require communicating beyond your own system. However, if you do want to use Pyscript and ChatGPT, follow other's steps addressing that by first searching the internet. Searching 'pyscript openai' in a search engine lead me to [here](https://medium.com/sopmac-labs/pyscript-examples-python-for-javascript-developers-51aa51bb0dc1). That clearly tells you what the issue is with `import openai` use in pyscript. It states, "While there is an ...

Comment: <continued>  official openai package for Python, only those packages listed in the following link are currently supported by PyScript:" (At the end of that quote in the actual post there is a link to the list of packages supported.) Pyscript doesn't work with all of core Python and definitely not with a lot of packages others have made. Things change fast though, so stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you ran the `pip install` command in a Python REPL.  You should run it in a Bash console on PythonAnywhere, instead.  Also, make sure that you install the package for the same Python version / virtual environment you use to run your web app.

EDIT: I misinterpreted the question.  To use Python dependencies in `py-script`, check the documentation for the `<py-config>` tag.

Comment: understood, but how can I run bash commands with py-script?

Comment: You cannot, Ariel. Caseneuve is missing that you are using [pyscript](https://pyscript.net/). In part, because you for some reason start talking later about trying `pip install`. And then you even ask at the end, "Is there a way to do it from Python itself?" Which is completely unrelated to pyscript use. The answer to "Is there a way to do it from Python itself?" is 'Yes', but it isn't going to help you with use of pyscript. Pyscript is browser based and because of security it really cannot see your files.

Comment: @Wayne is right, I edited my answer to address your question.