# How can I use "pip install" when using PyScript?

Tags: python, html, module, openai-api, pyscript

I am trying to code an html file that is able to contact with chat gpt.

this is the start of the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<py-script>
import openai
</py-script>
```

but when I run it it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'
```

any idea how I can install it just on the html file?

I tried to find out how to use:

`pip install openai` ,

but I dont know how to run bash commands from the python.

I also tried to use <py-env>, but it had no effect on the code whatsoever.

+ it could be blocked by my proxy, + I'm a beginner to python, so please explain it in simple terms.

Comment: + I am in school - i don't know that its relevant

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the contents of your `<py-config>` tag. It is quite possible that PyScript doesn't support the `openai` module yet.

Comment: did you mean <py-env> ?

Comment: @ArielBlau actually, no, I meant py-config as well. Check [this](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#importing-the-needed-libraries).

Comment: This is basically a refactoring of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75726034/8508004) by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Getting Started documentation](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#importing-the-needed-libraries), you import external modules using a `<py-config>` tag:

```html
<py-config>
    packages = ["openai"]
</py-config>
```

However, even with that, this code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <py-config>
        packages = ["openai"]
    </py-config>
    <py-script>
        import openai
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

gives the following error message:

> (PY1001): Unable to install package(s) 'openai'. Reason: Can't find a pure Python 3 Wheel for package(s) 'openai'. See: https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#micropip-can-t-find-a-pure-python-wheel for more information.

At the Pyodide link above is the following:

> Why can’t I just use `urllib` or `requests`?

> We currently can’t use such packages since sockets are not available in Pyodide. See [Write http.client in terms of Web APIs](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/project/roadmap.html#http-client-limit) for more information.

`openai` [requires `requests`](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/setup.cfg#L22), so until sockets are implemented in Pyodide (which is used by PyScript), you won't be able to use the `openai` module, or many others, in PyScript.

However, it is possible to make an async HTTP request using PyScript/Pyodide: see [this part of the docs](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/http-requests.html).

Comment: If the `<py-config>` tag is also used to declare dependencies, what is the point of the `<py-env>` tag?

Comment: This [freecodecamp article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/pyscript-python-front-end-framework/) and [RealPython article](https://realpython.com/pyscript-python-in-browser/#managing-python-dependencies-in-pyscript) seem to suggest that the latter is supposed to be used for importing any dependencies, but the docs don't even mention it. So, I'm confused...

Comment: @Übermensch According to [this commit](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/commit/c70e12107821145224ad4a34b5bc8fe4ecff9a8b) (I'm sure there's more info in the issues), `py-env` was removed entirely. There are several PRs and commits that completely scrub it from the docs. The articles you linked to are outdated. Always check the official docs first!

Comment: that makes sense, but could you give me an example on how to import openai then?

Comment: @ArielBlau See the second-to-last paragraph. You can't, currently. You can access a Web API using the code detailed in the link in the last paragraph. The wording I used may be confusing - you can't use the `requests` Python module, but you can make an async HTTP request using PyScript.

Comment: [I already pointed you to resources that covered much of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75726034/whenever-i-use-import-openai-in-pyscript-it-gives-an-error/75732924?noredirect=1#comment133608282_75726034), Ariel. This is why you don't just post the same question which a slight variation. It makes multiple people say the same thing because we cannot see what each other is answering.