# how to fix openai api error while using pyscript?

Tags: python, html, openai-api, pyscript

I am using pyscrypt to run a text rpg in the browser but I am getting this error when I try pip install openai:

Error: "(PY1001): Unable to install package(s) 'openai,matplotlib,pandas'. Reason: Can't find a pure Python 3 Wheel for package(s) 'openai,matplotlib,pandas'. See: https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#micropip-can-t-find-a-pure-python-wheel for more information."

My code:

```
  <head>
    <title>411</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <py-config>
      packages = ["openai", "matplotlib", "pandas"]
    </py-config>

  </body>
</html>
```

No error occurs when I do ["matplotlib", "pandas"] so this suggests to me its openai that is causing the issue

I have installed the openai package locally but no real luck there either

Answer (score 1):

The `openai` library is not directly usable in PyScript due to the lack of access to the `requests` package. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75738539/19718391) for more discussion on alternatives and possible workarounds.